# How to have a react application generate logs and transfer it to ELK?

Tags: reactjs, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a created a simple react application that calls an API and generate data(Weather Information) from that API. I have been told to integrate it with ELK Stack.
I don't know how to do it. I mean how to generate the logs from my react application and transfer it to ELK Stack.
Kindly Help.
There is **no backend language used**(It's just a Pure React Application)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about saving logs to the elastic then it is easy as calling an API.

As you are already calling API for getting weather details, in same way you can call API to send the log message to elastic as well.

You can call POST API to the elastic and send the log message to the required elastic index.

How to POST message to elastic index you can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)